# can't get what i need from DB

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

i have a query which returns a table. the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM vote_votes WHERE poll_id=? ORDER BY option_id ASC
```

for example when poll_id is 1, the table whould be:

```
poll_id | option_id | option_text 
------------------------------------- 
1              1         one
1              2         two
.              .          .
.              .          .
.              .          .
1              10        ten
```

now in my rest controller i want to have a method which returns the above query as a json.something like:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/polls/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Poll getOptions(int id) {
        return pollDao.getPollOptionsById(id);
    }
```

i already have a POJO named Poll which has properties like poll_id, option_id, option_text, title,description and other stuff.
what i've done is this:

```
private static final String SQL_GET_PollOptions_BY_ID = "SELECT * FROM vote_votes WHERE poll_id=? ORDER BY option_id ASC";

public Poll getPollOptionsById(int id) {

    try {
        List<Poll> poll = (List<Poll>) jdbcTemplate.query(SQL_GET_PollOptions_BY_ID, new PollOptionsExtractor(), id);
        return poll.get(0);
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

 private static class PollOptionsExtractor implements ResultSetExtractor {

        @Override
        public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            Map<Integer, Poll> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            Poll poll = null;
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("poll_id");
                int opt_id = rs.getInt("option_id");
                poll = map.get(id);
                if (poll == null) {
                    String opt_text = rs.getString("option_text");
                    poll = new Poll(id, opt_id, opt_text);
                    map.put(id, poll);
                }
            }
            return new ArrayList<>(map.values());
        }
    }
```

but when i go to `localhost:8080/polls/{id}` i can only see the first option_id and option_text of each poll_id.
note that up to 20 options is possible.

how can i get all options for a particular poll_id and not just one?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking. What specifically isn't working? What are you unsure of how to accomplish? How did this get an upvote?

Comment: i don't know how i can get it in jason. my json page only shows the first option of a particular poll_id. how can i get all options?

Comment: @Dave Newton : i have edited the question. please see it

Comment: Are you returning the data you think you are?

Comment: when i enter the url, a page comes up which has the data from DB in json format. for each poll_id, data are shown. the problem is i can not get all options. just one option is there. for example a poll has three options but i just get one option. is this still not clear?

Comment: It's clear-ish. Have you tried debugging your code? Your extractor returns a list of `Poll`. `getPollOptionsById` returns the first `Poll` in that list.